# giving value to table row and deleting it in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to give an id to each row in HTML, and when I enter that value into textbox, I want jquery to delete that row.

I have built this fiddle

**http://jsfiddle.net/vYAq9/3/**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $("#addbutton").click(function(){
     var uniqueid = $("#textbox1").val();
     var text = $("#textbox2").val();
     $("<tr><td>row content</td></tr>").val(uniqueid).html(text).appendTo("#table1");
  });

  $("#removebutton").click(function(){
      var uniqueid = $("#textbox1").val();
     //I want to find row with uniqueid, and remove it from the table
  });

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#addbutton").click(function () {
        var uniqueid = $("#textbox1").val();
        var text = $("#textbox2").val();
        $("<tr id=" + uniqueid + "><td>row content</td> </tr>").html(text).appendTo("#table1"); 
        // instead of value add an id | tr does not have a value!
    });

    $("#removebutton").click(function () {
        var uniqueid = $("#textbox1").val(); 
        $('#' + uniqueid).remove(); // use id to delete row with the same id
    });

});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/vYAq9/6/)

Comment: Remember `id`s must be unique, so if you go this route, be sure to prevent more than one row with the same id from being added.

Comment: will pick you as best answer in 5 mins (timeout)

Comment: @JasonP dont worry, it is coming from a unique Connection id, from C#, so it will come as unique. but thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

***[JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/vYAq9/10/)***

```
  $("#removebutton").click(function(){
      var uniqueid = $("#textbox1").val();
      $('#' + uniqueid).remove();
     //I want to find row with uniqueid, and remove from table
  });
```